# Flex child shrinks when applying "align-self: center"

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to horizontally center align a flex child inside a flex container.

However, when the child gets `align-self: center` it shrinks to width = 0.

Note that both the container and the child have `max-width`.

How would you solve this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* This causing the child to shrink to width = 0 */
  /* align-self: center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is the `stretch` effect that you disable by changing the alignment of the element. By default `align-items` is set to `stretch` thus the element will try to fill its parent width (or height for a row direction).

You can put back this feature using `width:100%`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  align-self: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

> `align-items` sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items. `align-self` **allows this default alignment to be overridden** for individual flex items.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)</sup>